# How Do I successfully Implement onDestroy() To Toast A Message?

Tags: android

I have a app, and when the activity is tabbed out and "swiped" then I want the app to toast a message. "Oof". I was looking through some stackoverflow questions, and I found this as an answer:

```
public void onDestroy() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks my dude",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

However this does not trigger upon my actions, nor when I force stop the app.

The toast, eventually will be replaced with a service call.

Comment: there is no guarantee that onDestroy is called

Comment: Try in `onStop()`

Comment: ondestory wont be called here. ondestory gets called when android cleans up its resources. onstop will probably be called b4 ondestory.

Comment: onStop is what I needed! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `onDestroy()` was called?
onDestroy() is called when

- The system is low on resources(memory, CPU time and so on) and makes a decision to kill your activity/application
- Somebody calls `finish()` on your activity
- An Activity is not reachable anymore
- You rotate the device
- Some similar situations

There is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` was even called.

Try this:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("TAG", "onDestroy called");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Oof",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

In your logcat, put a filter: TAG, check if any log is generated.
If this doesnt work, go with `onStop()`

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed and show the toast there ...

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Activity exiting!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't really work for me because I'm making a personal security app and I need to make sure certain actions occur when someone attempts to close the app, especially if its "armed".